# Edit master page

Tags: kentico

This is very basic question, but I can't figure it out.
Working on the existing Kentico project, and I want to update the Master page.
I can understand the editable body part, but where is this top meta tags and links come from and how can I remove those links or how to use new master page.

[image]

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These in particular are added automatically by Kentico. For example, the upper one is defined by the main stylesheet assigned to your site. Simply go to **Sites** application, edit your site and there you will see the stylesheet.